# adb push via usb between 2 android tabletes

Tags: android

i use  adb USB-interface to connect the two devices and i executed some shell command like ls mkdir but push and pull don't work
i am use a adb protocol description in this page https://www.assembla.com/code/android-gb-for-sharp-is01/git/nodes/system/core/adb/protocol.txt?rev=2d9be100b5ff94878f6149d3b5b80bce31bf0c02.
 i want to nkpw how i use the upload or the file brige with the open command???